# Select only IDs of customers that have orders in every year

Tags: mysql, group-by

Somehow I am getting the wrong customer IDs, I only want the IDs that have ordered in every year at least once since the date of the first order.

Table `orders`:

```
o_id   o_c_id   o_type    o_date
1345   13       TA        2015-01-01
7499   13       TA        2015-01-16
7521   15       GA        2015-01-08
7566   16       TA        2016-01-24
7654   15       FB        2016-01-28
```

Table `customers`:

```
c_id   c_name    c_email
13     Trump     example@gmail.com          
14     Obama     example@gmail.com
15     Miguel    example@gmail.com
16     Dequavo   example@gmail.com
```

My query:

```sql
SELECT c_id, YEAR(o_date), c_email
FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(o_date) BETWEEN YEAR(MIN(o_date)) AND YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(o_date)
HAVING COUNT(c_id) > 0
ORDER BY c_id
```

Comment: You do realise that with the provided data you would end up not getting any results right? (no orders in 2017)

Comment: Bad Group By, very bad !!

Comment: besides criticizing can u give me helpful information thank you

Comment: Peter M your right i edited my query it was something i tried to get the years dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS indoor question you're only asking for the `Customer ID` I've got you an example of what you might be looking for. Feel free to change the query as I'm only selecting the `o_c_id` assuming that is the `Customer ID`

```
SELECT 
  o_c_id
FROM
  orders
GROUP BY 
  o_c_id
HAVING 
  (MIN(YEAR(o_date)) + COUNT(DISTINCT(YEAR(o_date))) -1) = YEAR(NOW())
```

This should give you a list of all the `o_c_id` that have placed an order every year since their first order.

Comment: Maybe i asked my question wrong sorry but by first order i didnt mean the first order of that one specific customer i meant just in general

Comment: @Regan: Then replace `MIN(YEAR(o_date))` by `(SELECT MIN(YEAR(o_all.o_date)) FROM orders o_all)`.